# Obtain absolute extrem values given f continuous and bounded

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**: Given $f:\ \mathbb{R}\  \to \ \mathbb{R}, $ a continuous and bounded function, describe a method to get its absolute maximum and absolute minimum.

**My approach**: We will start the proces at $[-1,1]$ and apply successively the Extreme Value Theorem in ordrer to get the maximum and minimum values of a particular set, and then compare them. By iterating this process we will get the extrem values of the whole function:

Consider the interval $[-1,1]$. By the EVT we get that $f([0,1]) = [f(c_{min}), f(c_{max})]$ where $f(c_{min}), f(c_{max})$ are the local minimum and maximum respectively. Now consider the interval $[-2, 2]$ apply the ETV and compare the new values with the previous ones (put them in a set and compute max, min). If we keep doing this process, we will end up with the extreme values of the whole funcion $f$.

- Is there any fancier way to do this process? I find my answer is incomplete, there should be an idea that maybe leads to a more elegant process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't have to have a global minimum or maximum, e.g. arctan.

Comment: You are completely right. But even then, I rather thought that the goal was to find the upper and lower bound. Anyway, maybe more information about the function would be needed to find the upper/lower bounds. Thank you.